# long string not update on sqlite db - php

Tags: php, string

I have a little problem with a php page that display an sqlite database and get the possibility to edit some value.
My problem is that short string are write on my database while large string are not write on database.
This is my code:
(i think that there are a lot of error, but I don't know php :( )

```
<div id="editor">

        <?php
            if($_POST['NewText']){  
                $textNew = $_POST['textAreaTesto'];

                $db->exec("UPDATE Argomenti_".$_SESSION[sessioneMateria]." SET Testo='".$textNew."' WHERE ID='".$idTestoSelezionato."'");   

                echo ("UPDATE Argomenti_".$_SESSION[sessioneMateria]." SET Testo='testo' WHERE ID='".$idTestoSelezionato."'");  
            }
        ?>

        <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
            <textarea id="textAreaTesto" name="textAreaTesto" cols=50 rows=30><?php echo $TestoSelezionato;?></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="NewText" class='btn' value="invia testo">
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could reduce this code down to something that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Hold on, what's this? `$_POST['textAreaTesto'].decode("utf-8")`

Comment: edit code of my problem...Is a way that I use (is a test) for encode the text with utf-8 (some tips get around of internet...but is an old test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) take advantage of prepared statements:

```
$textNew = $_POST['textAreaTesto'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `Argomenti_{$_SESSION['sessioneMateria']}` 
    SET Testo=:text
    WHERE ID=:id");   

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':text' => $textNew,
    ':id' => $idTestoSelezionato,
));
```

Please note that if `$_SESSION['sessioneMateria']` is populated with a user submitted value, you should sanitize it (i.e. make sure it only contains alphabets, etc.).

Comment: thank you but nothing, in this way I can't update my database :(, $_SESSION['sessioneMateria'] is populated by me so is correct.

Comment: it's so strange, I use this:$textNew = $_POST['textAreaTesto']; $query = "UPDATE Argomenti_$_SESSION[sessioneMateria] SET Testo = '$textNew' WHERE ID = '$idTestoSelezionato'"; $db->exec($query); and seems to work but, if i copy/paste text from (for ex.) text edit not work, if I write the text work!

Comment: @kikko088 Well, if your text contains single quotes, your query would fail because it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: at the end the problem are singles quotes! thank you, I encoding/deconding string and now is ok!